# Powershell runspace unexpected output (misunderstanding?)

Tags: powershell

```
$ScriptBlock = {
Param (
    $Vm,
    $vc,
    $session)
$VCenter = Connect-VIServer -Server $vc -session $session -force
$status = Get-VM $Vm
Write-host $status.Name
if ($status.PowerState -eq "PoweredOff")
                {
                    $Clone = '_2.2'

                    $NewVM = $Vm + $Clone
Write-host $NewVM.Name
}
}
            $Results = @()
            $Throttle = 5 #threads
            $sesssionstate = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()
            $sesssionstate.ImportPSModule("Vmware.VimAutomation.Core")
            $RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $Throttle, $sesssionstate, $host)
            $RunspacePool.Open()
            $Jobs = @()

            $Vms = gc .\vmlist.txt
    Foreach ($Vm in $Vms)
            {
                #Start-Sleep -Minutes 1
                $Job = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($Vm).AddArgument($con.Name).AddArgument($con.SessionId)
                $Job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
                $Jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Job     = $Job
                    Result  = $Job.BeginInvoke()
                }

            }
while ($Jobs -Contains $false) {}
foreach($Job in $jobs)
{
    $results += $Job.Job.EndInvoke($Job.Result)
    $Job.Job.Dispose()
}

$results
```

Input File:

```
INTCLWK8
INTCLWK82
INTCLWK83
```

Output:

```
INTCLWK8
INTCLWK8_2.2
INTCLWK82
INTCLWK82_2.2
INTCLWK83
INTCLWK83_2.2
```

2nd run:

```
INTCLWK8
INTCLWK8_2.2
INTCLWK82_2.2
INTCLWK83
INTCLWK82
INTCLWK83_2.2
```

Why is the output different at run? This caused confusion to write multithread.
The output should be always like the below.

```
INTCLWK8
INTCLWK8_2.2
INTCLWK82
INTCLWK82_2.2
INTCLWK83
INTCLWK83_2.2
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but that's when you get when you parallelize. Don't use `write-host` but return your determined values to your main script to work with your data.

Comment: Initially i wasn’t add write-host in to the script and the script wasn’t run properly and thrown error and this is intermittent. Hence I tried to output the value before each step and found this behaviour. This could cause the script not run properly. The main problem is how the “_2.2” get into other thread. Each thread should return only respective vm then follow by its “_2.2” vm. Anything wrong in the script.

Comment: Another strange behaviour with code seen “INTCLWK8_2.2INTCLWK82_2.2” together. Very strange to run further in production environment. All this problem is intermittent only. Sometime it ran as expected.. any code change needed?

Comment: There is nothing out of the ordinary here. You are using asynchronous execution, so the results will show in the order that it completed and not in the order that it was invoked. Like @hcm said, you should be returning it to main script, and then displaying it to preserve the order of invoking.

Comment: In the new object you can add a `Name` property to identify each job uniquely. This will allow you to use `$Jobs | Where-object {$_.Name -eq "<myjobname>"}` filter

Comment: The strange behavior of “INTCLWK8_2.2INTCLWK82_2.2” occurs due to `Write-host` not automatically adding a new line character.

Comment: @Sid when the input INTCLWK8 passed from the thread and get it to scriptblock it should completed the full block line by line right? Which means the output should be INTCLWK8 follow by  INTCLWK8_2.2 right? How the other one get in here (console)“INTCLWK82_2.2 before  INTCLWK82

Comment: @shaikabdul Yes, that should not happen. that could be a bug with how powershell internally handles returns from multiple threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204985/discussion-between-shaik-abdul-and-sid).

Comment: The why don't you sort the results like this: `$results | Sort-Object`

Comment: My doubt is runspace running independently?how do I Ensure this . If I can corner this then will follow further